# VSTS BuildAgent can not find the installed certificate

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am following this article to sign my UWP packages via VSTS build agent:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps#certificates-best-practices

I choose the option *'pick from certificate store'* in my Package.appmanifest.
And I installed the certificate on the Build Agent.

But my build task fails with the following error:
"*A certificate with thumbprint 'xxxxxx' that is specified in the project cannot be found in the certificate store. Please specify a valid thumbprint in the project file.*"

am I missing something here?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case, if it helps someone, The problem was that the VSO Agent(xxxx) Windows Service was running as ‘Local Service’ logon account, I had to change that to build Agent user, now the build task is able to find the certificate.